# Asymptotic approximation of $\int_1^x \frac{| \sin t|}{t}dt$ as $x \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that:

$$\int_1^x  \frac{| \sin t|}{t}dt \sim \frac{2}{\pi} \ln x \quad \mathrm{as} \quad x \to \infty$$

I was trying to find a function $g$ such that $\frac{|\sin t|}{t} \underset{x \to \infty}{\sim} g$, but I don't know if it is a good way to start. Also, L'Hôpital's rule does not work in this case.Do you have any hints?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fourier series give a way:
$$ \left|\sin x\right| = \frac{2}{\pi}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(2nx)}{4n^2-1}=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1-\cos(2nx)}{4n^2-1}\tag{1} $$
leads to
$$ \int_{1}^{x}\frac{\left|\sin t\right|}{t}\,dt =\frac{2}{\pi}\,\log(x)-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{4n^2-1}\int_{1}^{x}\frac{\cos(2nt)}{t}\,dt\tag{2}$$
where the remainder term bounded by an absolute constant, due to:

$$ \int_{1}^{x}\frac{\cos(2nt)}{t}\,dt = \underbrace{\left.\frac{\sin(2nt)}{2nt}\right|_{1}^{x}}_{\text{bounded}}+\underbrace{\int_{1}^{x}\frac{\sin(2nt)}{2nt^2}\,dt}_{\text{bounded}}\tag{3}$$We are simply stating that in the original integral we are allowed to replace $\left|\sin t\right|$ with its mean value without affecting the main term of the asymptotics, by integration by parts and [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test).

Answer (score 2):

First we split integral $I=[1,x]$ into the subintervals $I_n = [(n-1)\pi, n\pi] \cap I$ for $n=1,..., n^*=\lceil x/\pi \rceil$. In each interval, we have
$$ \frac{1}{n\pi} \leq \frac1 t \leq \frac{1}{(n-1)\pi} \quad \text{for } t \in I_n.$$
Using the fact that $\int_0^\pi\!dt\,\sin t =2$,  we have the estimate
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\log x\sim\frac{2}{\pi} \log(n^*/2)=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_2^{n^*}\,\frac{dt}{t}\leq\sum_{n=2}^{n^*-1} \frac{2}{n\pi}\leq \int_\pi^x \!dt\,\frac{|\sin t|}{t} \leq  \sum_{n=2}^{n^*} \frac{2}{(n-1)\pi} \leq \frac{2}{\pi} \int_1^{n^*}\,\frac{dt}{t}=\frac{2}{\pi} \log(n^*) \sim \frac{2}{\pi}\log x.$$

Now as $$\int_1^x \!dt\,\frac{|\sin t|}{t}=\int_1^\pi \!dt\,\frac{|\sin t|}{t} + \int_\pi^x \!dt\,\frac{|\sin t|}{t} $$ with the first term a constant, we have the result.

Answer (score 2):

> > **First Hint.** If $g\to\infty$ and $|f-g|$ is bounded then $\frac fg\to1$.

(Proof: $\frac fg-1=\frac{f-g}g$.)

> > **Second Hint.** There exists $c<\infty$ such that $$\left|\int_A^{A+2\pi}\left(\frac2\pi-|\sin(y)|\right)\frac{dy}y\right|\le\frac c{A^2}$$for all $A\ge1$.

Hint: Since $\frac2\pi$ is the average of $|\sin(y)|$ over any interval of length $2\pi$ it follows that $$\int_A^{A+2\pi}\left(\frac2\pi-|\sin(y)|\right)\frac{dy}y=\int_A^{A+2\pi}\left(\frac2\pi-|\sin(y)|\right)\left(\frac1y-\frac1A\right){dy};$$note that $\frac1y-\frac1A=\frac{A-y}{Ay}$.